# I keep getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'originStackTrace' of null" in electron I can't seem to find out why?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

It happened when I tried to submit a form

Javascript

```
 this.submitForm = (formID) => {
        let {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");

        const myData = $(`#${formID}`).serialize();

        ipcRenderer.sendSync("create-form-data",myData);
    };
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-9">
            <form onsubmit="theTemplate.submitForm('createForm')" id="createForm" action="GET" class="tab-content">
                <div id="goal" data-tab-content class="active form-group">
                    <h1>Goal</h1>
                    <label>What is your desired outcome?</label>
                    <input name="goalOne" type="text" class="form-control">

                    <label>What type of person achieves that outcome?</label>
                    <input name="goalTwo" type="text" class="form-control" >
```

googling tends not to produce any results. And i have no idea what "origin stack trace" is.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-9">
            <form onsubmit="submitForm(event,'createForm')" id="createForm" action="GET" class="tab-content">
                <div id="goal" data-tab-content class="active form-group">
                    <h1>Goal</h1>
                    <label>What is your desired outcome?</label>
                    <input name="goalOne" type="text" class="form-control">

                    <label>What type of person achieves that outcome?</label>
                    <input name="goalTwo" type="text" class="form-control" >
                    <input type='submit'/>
                 </div>
             </form>
</div>
<script>
  const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
     if(element.name) //For skip the named value
     data[element.name] = element.value;
     return data;
  }, {})

  const submitForm = (event, formID) => {
    event.preventDefault()
  
    //let {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");
    const myData= formToJSON(event.target)
    console.log(myData)

    //ipcRenderer.sendSync("create-form-data",myData);
  };
</script>
```

Please check this code snippet. This is just for extract the form data as your needs. I changed some your **html** and **js** code. This will extract from data in **JSON** format.

Then copy this to your project and enable the ipc part. Then this will send the JSON data to main process successfully.

To know how to communicate between **main** and **renderer** process. Please check this answer.

[how to communicate between react and electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681069/how-to-communicate-between-react-and-electron/59681218#59681218)